# How to call a S4 class obj in a function?

Tags: r, jdbc, r-s4, rjdbc

Please look at the below code:

```
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass=Driver class path, classPath=JarFile location)
jdbcConnection <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, Driver, Username,Password)
```

I am able to successfully establish a connection, with the above code,

The problem arises when i try to call the connection obj (jdbcConnection), inside a function to query something,

For example,

```
runQuery <- function(query,jdbcConnection)
{
print(jdbcConnection)
queryResult <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, query)
}
```

gives me "Error in print(jdbcConnection) : argument "jdbcConnection" is missing, with no default".

So the question is how to pass the connection obj to a function, which is of "S4 object of Class JDBCConnection" ??

Comment: That should have worked I think — did you definitely specify *both* arguments to `runQuery`? If the second argument was missing, then you can still call `runQuery` without initial error due to lazy evaluation, but when it tries to print the connection the error will occur.

Comment: I missed this, so both the code snips are in two different files, so when i run the code in first snip, it calls the function declared in the other file. So, when this happens R couldnt get the obj